# How to get the values picked from angularjs modal in textbox?

Tags: angularjs

In Angularjs I want to show the values in textbox picked from modal in ng-repeat. How can I do this?

Comment: Can you show us what you've got so far?

Comment: If you use angular bootstrap UI you can do it easily, as explained here - https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal

Comment: It's not possible to answer, too generic. The best answer I can provide: 1. take the value from the modal. 2. bind to the text field model.

Comment: please give me the example how you bind to the text field model

Comment: How are you picking value from ng-repeat....Plz elaborate little more

Comment: there is ng-repeat and at every row modal link is there and as we picked the value from the modal then the picked value and modal is closed. The picked value should be displayed on the textbox

Answer (score 0):

In html view:

```
<input ng-model="batchno_qty[$index]">
```

In controller:

```
$scope.show_qty=function(item_id,index){
$scope.current_index=index;
$scope.batchno_qty1=[];
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'opportunities/show_qty_popup.php',
        controller: pick_supplier,
        scope: $scope,
        resolve: {current_index: function () {
                    return $scope.current_index;
                  }
                }
    });
    modalInstance.result.then(function (response) {
        $scope.response=response;
        $scope.batchno_qty=[]; 
     });        
    }

    function pick_supplier($scope, $modalInstance,current_index)
    {       
     $scope.batch_select=[];
     $scope.selected_qty=[];
    $scope.pick_qty = function (itemid) {   
        $scope.array_qty=[];
        $scope.pick={};
        if($scope.batch_select.length==0)
        {
            Notification.error("No Batch no. is selected.");
        }
        else
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.batch_select.length; i++) 
            {
                if($scope.batch_select[i]==undefined)
                {
                    //Notification("your Batch no. is undefined.");
                }
                else
                {
                    if($scope.selected_qty[i]==undefined)
                    {
                        Notification("Please enter quantity.");
                    }
                    else
                    {       
                $scope.pick[$scope.batch_select[i]]
                  =$scope.selected_qty[i];  

                    }
                }
            }
        }
                    $scope.total_pick=0;

        $scope.set=1;
        supplier_result.itemid=itemid
        $modalInstance.close($scope.pick);
      }
     }
```